# PHP Приведение SQL таблицы к нужному виду

Tags: php, mysql, sql, update, библиотека

Решил создать библиотеку, но сначала хотел узнать, может уже есть что-то готовое.

Смысл: не заходить каждый раз в phpmyadmin и не писать вручную патчи для обновления структуры. В простом php файле я создаю шаблон, указывая какая у нас должна быть таблица в БД, например:

```
table users (
id int(11) primary autoinc,
login varchar(60),
age int default "18",
email varchar(60),
comment text
);
```

и можно указать несколько таких таблиц.

Скрипт подключается к БД и делает следующее:

- проверяет, существует ли такая таблица, если нет то создаёт
- проверяет, существуют ли такие поля в таблице, если нет, то создаёт
- проверяет, соответствует ли каждое поле заданному типу, если нет, то обновляет тип поля
- аналогично со значениями по умолчанию
- в идеале ещё порядок полей чтобы обновлял как в шаблоне (но не знаю, насколько это реализуемо).

Думаю это сильно упростит и ускорит работу - изменяю один файл update_db.php и обновляю файлы на сервере. Не нужно писать патчи, не нужно лазать в phpmyadmin.

Comment: Если таблицы нет, то она создаётся, зачем птом выполнять 2 и 3 пункт?

Comment: "Миграция" называется. Подбирай любой под свои нужды.

Comment: @Bloom , Если таблицы нет и она создаётся по шаблону - то 2,3 пункты, конечно, не выполняются. А вот если таблица уже есть какая-то с таким названием, то выполняем остальные пункты. Пункты не отражают алгоритм работы, а только описывают функционал библиотеки.

Comment: напиши сам, проверку elseif() и по порядку

Comment: @AlexanderOleynikov , миграции это немного не то. Как я понял - миграции это как раз про патчи. А нужно чтобы сколько бы раз я не запускал update_db.php у меня все таблицы приводились к нужному виду (т.е. я указываю именно структуру, а не какие изменения мне нужно сделать). И код такой библиотеки уместится в сотню строк.

Comment: @Bloom , я так и планирую, если ничего готового не найду.

Comment: @DarkWizard, вот только если таблица уже не просто есть, а ещё и заполнена какими-то данными, то простым alter table...  для смены, скажем, типа поля (если оно есть и уже заполнено) вы воспользоваться не сможете.

Comment: Не совсем по теме вопроса - но не делай юзерам  поле возраст. Лучше год рождения :)

Answer (score 0):

Описанное вами называется идемпотентностью (сколько раз ни выполняй - результат один и тот же) - но миграции на практике зачастую описывают изменения в базе данных, которые нельзя вывести путем сравнения начального и конечного состояний схемы, поскольку у инструмента недостаточно информации, чтобы знать, как перенести существующие данные.

**Несколько примеров:**

***Переименование таблицы, колонки, etc*** - думаю тут все понятно

***Разделение или объединение столбцов*** - при разделении столбца можно создать два или более новых столбца и удалить исходный столбец. Аналогично, объединение столбцов создаст новый столбец и удалит исходные столбцы. В любом случае при идемпотентном сценарии любые данные в удаленных столбцах будут потеряны.

***Изменение типа данных или размера столбца*** - при замене типа данных столбца, например с INT на SMALLINT, данные могут быть усечены

***Работа с большими перемещениями данных*** - такие операции, как удаление столбца или добавление NOT NULL столбца со значением по умолчанию, могут занять много времени и создать много записей в журнале, крупномасштабные миграции данных в таких условиях лучше всего делать постепенно в отдельных разбиваемых партиях

***etc***

Comment: я не затрагиваю работу с данными и не удаляю поля. Также я думаю что вообще не придётся менять тип поля с bigint На int, скорее наоборот. Да и в этом случае можно вывести предупреждение. Сейчас интересует только работа со структурой.

Comment: @DarkWizard все бывает в первый раз